# How to place 3 boxes nex to each other with some text inside it?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to put 3 boxes (exactly with the same size) next to each other. Also I need to make sure that they fit equally in the screen.

But in my case, problem is with the third box, it doesn't stay in the same line like two others, it just jumps down and stay below others.

I am showing what I have done so far, but I am not sure if they are smartly coded. Do you have any suggestion to improve my code? I am pretty new in HTML and CSS!

.HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="eng">
    <head>
        <title> Put your title</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index_akin_design.css">

    </head>

    <body>
        <h1><i>Logo</i>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Header goes here</h1>
                <br /><br />


                <br/><br/><br/>


            <p id="p_box1">Text goes here Text goes here Text goes here<br/>
                        Text goes here Text goes here Text goes here<br/>
                        Text goes here Text goes here Text goes here<br/></p>


            <p id="p_box2">Text goes here Text goes here Text goes here<br/>
                        Text goes here Text goes here Text goes here<br/>
                        Text goes here Text goes here Text goes here<br/></p>   


            <p id="p_box3">Text goes here Text goes here Text goes here<br/>
                        Text goes here Text goes here Text goes here<br/>
                        Text goes here Text goes here Text goes here<br/></p>   


    </body>



</html>
```

.CSS:

```
    *{

margin:0px;
padding:0px;
}
body{

width:100%;
-webkit-box-pack:center;
-moz-box-pack:center;
box-pack:center;

}

h1,body{

display:block;
}

h1{
text-align:center;
margin-top:55px;
color:green;
font-family:Accord SF;
border-bottom:2px solid Crimson ;
padding-bottom:10px;
}
#p_box1{
border:1px solid red;
margin-left:60px;
padding-left:30px;
padding-right:30px;
padding-top:70px;
padding-bottom:70px;
float:left;
}

#p_box2{

border:1px solid red;
margin-left:450px;
margin-right:550px;
padding-left:30px;
padding-right:30px;
padding-top:70px;
padding-bottom:70px;
float:middle;

}
#p_box3{
border:1px solid red;

margin-left:850px;

margin-right:61px;


padding-left:30px;
padding-right:30px;
padding-top:70px;
padding-bottom:70px;


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `%` and cleanup you code

```css
*{box-sizing:border-box;padding:0; margin:0}

h1{
    text-align:center;
    margin-top:55px;
    color:green;
    font-family:Accord SF;
    border-bottom:2px solid Crimson ;
    padding-bottom:10px;
}
[id^=p_box]{
    padding: 18px 2%;
    border: 1px solid red;
    float: left;
    width: 29.333333%;
    margin: auto 2%;  
}
#p_box1{
    background-color:green;
}
#p_box2{
    background-color:red;
}
#p_box3{
    background-color:yellow;
}
```

```html
 <h1><i>Logo</i>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Header goes here</h1>
                <br /><br />


                <br/><br/><br/>


            <p id="p_box1">Text goes here Text goes here Text goes here<br/>
                        Text goes here Text goes here Text goes here<br/>
                        Text goes here Text goes here Text goes here<br/></p>


            <p id="p_box2">Text goes here Text goes here Text goes here<br/>
                        Text goes here Text goes here Text goes here<br/>
                        Text goes here Text goes here Text goes here<br/></p>   


            <p id="p_box3">Text goes here Text goes here Text goes here<br/>
                        Text goes here Text goes here Text goes here<br/>
                        Text goes here Text goes here Text goes here<br/></p>
```

Comment: no u missunderstood it. i want 3 boxes next to each other. third box also shoud stay next to second one

Comment: i was updating the fiddle check it again.

Comment: thank you very very much, thats what I wanted. Two things I just need to understand: (1)what does [id^=p_box] mean?   (2) How did you calculate the padding (%) and width(%) so quickly without using much effort?   (3) what does box-sizing:border-box  do?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing   and `[id^=p_box] ` means find all `id`s starting with `p_box`